# Swapping values by pointer

Tags: c

I feel like this probably isn't the best idea, but I've implemented a generic swap function in C like so:

```
void swap(void** p1, void** p2) {
    void* temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;
}
```

However, I am having difficulties calling this function. `swap(&&a, &&b)` for integers a and b doesn't work as '&&' is the label operator, and `swap(&(&a), &(&b))` gives the error 'lvalue required as unary '&' operand'. How should I call this function?

Edit: changed variable names for clarity

Edit: I'm trying to do the following, but, as &a and &b seem to be read-only ('lvalue required as left operand of assignment'), it doesn't work:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 3;
int* temp = &a;
&a = &b;
&b = temp;
assert(a == 3);
assert(b == 5);
```

Comment: Types of `l_limit` and `u_limit`? Why do you think you need `&&` and not just `&` ?

Comment: I think you should show some more code. The calling function and the variable definitions.

Comment: `void swap(void *p1, void *p2, size_t obj_size);`

Comment: This is not a generic swap function. This is a function to swap two void pointers. It will not swap two integers or strings or enums even if you are able to form pointers to these things. Pointers don't work this way. For some insight on how they do work, consider `memcpy`. It can be viewed as a generic assignment function. Now a generic swap would need three generic assignments in it, wouldn't it?

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve?

Comment: What I was trying to do is to swap a and b by swapping the memory addresses associated with a and b, rather than swapping the values. This isn't necessary for integers, but could be for structs or arrays.

Comment: @John3136 Passing `&a` and `&b` won't work, as this just passes the values of the memory locations. After leaving the scope of the function, the variables a and b would be unchanged.

Comment: @n.m. my thought process assumes that the pointers would be cast to void pointers automatically, in the same way that an int is cast to a double when the two are used in a binary operation. As the value is not used in the function, only the memory location, this use should be valid?

Comment: You cannot swap two houses by swapping two pieces of paper with their street addresses written on them. You need to physically move bricks from place to place.

Comment: @n.m. I disagree. You only need to swap the house numbers in order to divert traffic originally meant for each house to the other.

Comment: It's your approach that is not working, not mine. What do you mean by "swapping the house numbers"? Physically affixing new plagues with numbers to the houses? This may not work very well if everyone expects Main Street 40  to be right next to Main Street 42. Do you think every byte in your computer have a little plaque with an address which you can set at will? It doesn't work like that.

Comment: @n.m. I'm sorry, I don't think you understand. I have discovered that you cannot manually set the memory location of a variable (`&a = &b`), but, as a newcomer to c, this is not immediately apparent. I can't see a logical flaw in saying 'I want variable a to refer to the value in the memory location currently referenced by `b`. However, this is not supported by the language.

Comment: `you cannot manually set the memory location of a variable` Yes, that's exactly the problem. You cannot manually set the memory location of a variable. It is an inherent property of a variable. This is why your idea of affixing a new number to a house doesn't quite translate to memory addresses.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use `swap(&(&l_limit), &(&u_limit))` since `&l_limit` evaluates to a temporary rvalue pointer whose address cannot be taken. Same problem exists for `&&u_limit` also.

You need to use:

```
void* ptr1 = &l_limit;
void* ptr2 = &u_limit;
swap(&ptr1, &ptr2);
```

Comment: @n.m. Fair enough. I am *guessing* he needs them.

Comment: A *generic* swap function.

Comment: @n.m. as opposed to implementing swap_int(int*, int*), swap_double(double*, double*), etc. for each type

Comment: @Dimpl yes, I understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Dimpl To reiterate, this answer shows how to swap ptr1 and ptr2, which is very different from swapping l_limit and u_limit. Do you really want that?

Comment: @n.m. No, I don't. I accepted this answer as it essentially stated that &l_limit is read-only, so the approach I am trying to take is doomed to fail. This is the next best thing.

Comment: @Dimpl The answer by muXXmit2X is exactly the generic swap routine you wanted to write. You may want to accept it instead, or perhaps just read and understand how it works.

Comment: @n.m. I'm not familiar with memcpy, but I believe muXXmit2X's solution copies the values between the memory locations, rather than changing which location is being referred to. I don't think the question is solvable due to restrictions of the language.

Comment: @Dimpl That's what the generic swap is supposed to do. It's not "a restriction of a language" as you put it, but rather an inherent property of current computer architectures.

Answer (score 3):

As n.m. pointed out, to get a real generic swap function you should consider using `memcpy`. It can be used as a generic assignement.

Your `swap` will then look like this:

```
void swap(void *a, void *b, size_t s)
{
    void *tmp = malloc(s);
    if (tmp) 
    {
        memcpy(tmp, a, s);
        memcpy(a, b, s);
        memcpy(b, tmp, s);
    }
    free(tmp);
}
```

And can be used like so:

```
#define MAX 256

int main()
{
    // works for primitive types
    int a = 4, b = 5;
    swap( &a, &b, sizeof(int));
    printf("%d %d\n", a , b);

    // as well as for pointers
    char cA[MAX] = "World!";
    char cB[MAX] = "Hello ";
    swap( &cA, &cB, MAX); 
    printf("%s%s\n", cA, cB); 
}
```

This will safely swap the values without the need of pointers to pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You are right on one point: this probably isn't the best idea.

You are not swapping two pieces of data, you are swapping the values two pointers that happen to point to them, but the data stays in place.

Assume for instance

```
int a= 3, b= 5;
int* pa= &a, * qa= &a, * pb= &b, * qb= &b;
```

After your "swap" is called with `pa` and `pb`, `a` and `b` still contain `3` and `5`, `pa` points to `5` and `pb` to `3`, but `qa` still points to `3` and `qb` to `5`.

Also note that without two properly initialized pointer variables, you just *can't* call your swap.

Comment: I know, which is why I was trying to use &(&a) and &(&b). However, from the feedback to this thread, it looks like this kind of behaviour is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
int varA = 5, varB = 10;
int *pA = &varA;
int *pB = &varB;
swap((void**)&pA, (void**)&pA);
```

Now `pA` points to `varB` and `pB` points to `varA`